# Предложение с однородными членами

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

> Футболист, игравший в нападении *и который* забил два гола, был воспитанником известного тренера.

Нужна ли запятая перед *и который*? Или предложение вообще неверно?

Answer (score 2):

Предложение нуждается в правке.

***Футболист, игравший в нападении и  забивший два гола, был воспитанником известного тренера.***

В Вашем предложениии причастный оборот и придаточное предложение употреблены как однородные члены. Замените их на два однородных определения, выраженных причастными оборотами. Запятая не нужна, союз И одиночный, употреблён между двумя однородными членами.